# Automated testing Geb - IntelliJ error when extending Page or Module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, geb

Is there a way to extend a Page or Module class in Geb, without implementing the waitFor() methods? My application is working but it's annoying when IntelliJ undelines my code here:

```
class HomePage extends Page {
...
}
```

and in the project view.

The error message is as follows:

> Method 'waitFor' is not implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression introduced in Geb 0.12.0. Your code will work even though IntelliJ underlines it so you can safely ignore it. If it's annoying you though then you can always revert to 0.10.0.

I plan to release a 0.12.1 with this and one other issue fixed when I'm back from holidays.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your project with a default wait time as explained [here](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#content-dsl-wait) and as shown [here](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#default-waiting-configuration).  The timeout value specified in waiting will become your default value.  There are additional timeouts that can be referred to by a symbolic name rather than by a number, also shown on that page.